# Как преобразовать word документ в html страницу без тысяч строк избыточного кода?

Tags: html, ms-word, type-conversion

Имею такой вопрос:
Как я могу преобразовать текстовый документ в html-страницу без тысяч строк избыточного кода и с сохранением форматирования? (Кроме ручного) Есть ли программа (и какая?), которая может это сделать? Какие программы вы используете для этой цели?

Потому что, когда я делаю это через программу Word или через онлайн-конвертеры, которые я пробовал до сих пор, я получаю несколько тысяч строк избыточного (лишнего) кода.

Например, документ Word из трех страниц - они конвертируют его в более чем 2000 строк html-кода?! И даже если я это делаю через саму программу Word (сохранять как HTML) - форматирование не сохраняется корректно и код все равно больше 2000 строк - на три страницы текста.

А еще у меня есть статьи в формате Word, некоторые из которых составляют порядка 60-70 страниц, и я хочу их загрузить на сайт, но не хочу получать десятки тысяч строк html-кода!

А если я сделаю это вручную - это займет у меня месяцы...

Comment: Пробовали вариант сохранения как [веб-страницы с фильтром](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-d1cf1c33-e854-4f9d-bd51-93f94da0f4e3)? Тоже не идеально, но мусора значительно меньше

Comment: может лучше отформатировать его и оставить расширение .txt?  браузеры великолепно показывают и текстовые файлы.

Comment: Я думаю, что для файлов большего размера соотношение (HTML lines)/(Word pages) должно быть меньше.